Testing signing with Firebase authentication in Go
I a service in Go and I'm currently porting it from Auth0 to Firebase. A few of the tests in our test suite are there to ensure that our authentication code works correctly, e.g. sign in a few test users, check that the middleware parses correctly their authorizations.
Now, I'd like to port these tests to Firebase auth. For this, I'd need the ability to sign in from the test suite, preferably on the emulator, but if necessary we have a Firebase project dedicated to testing.
Here's what I've tried:

I've attempted to sign in from the Go Firebase SDK, but it doesn't seem to support signing in.
I've attempted to setup the emulator, but the Go SDK doesn't seem to support the emulator.
I've looked for the documentation of the REST API for the emulator, but I can't find anything about a signin.
I've tried to setup a client JS app, look at its REST calls, and replicate them, but for some reason, the emulator returns 500 to every request I make from a server.
I've attempted to look at the source code of the Flutter SDK, which uses the C++ SDK, which very quickly gets confusing and I get lost in that code.
I've attempted to sign in to the emulator from the CLI, but I can't find any
So now I'm trying to implement "sign up with email link" using a real Firebase project (dedicated to testing) and I'm in a wild goose chase of configuring all sorts of things that I'm sure are really useful for a real project, but wasting lots of time for what should be a simple test. I'm starting to suspect that it's the wrong path.

What am I doing wrong? How do Go developers test their sign-in with firebase?
P.S.: Yes, we're going to mock the authentication for most tests, but it's team policy that we need at least one test that actually goes through an official server or emulator.

The only SDK that Firebase providers for Go developer is a so-called Admin SDK, that allows them to perform administrative tasks on their Firebase projects. Signing in to a project with Firebase Authentication is not such an administrative task, so it is not a feature of the Firebase SDK for Go developers.
If you need to implement this specific use-case, you can call the REST API for Firebase Authentication, although I don't immediately see the option to sign in with an email link in there either - so you may have to try some of the documented options first and then use the API explorer to see what else there is.

Yes, that's absolutely my problem. And yes, what you're describing is my 7.
